# S3: What event (in target bucket) is generated when a file is replicated to target bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge

When a file is uploaded in s3 it generates an s3 event [Object Created](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventBridge.html).

I am wondering ( couldn't find in documentation) what kind of event is generated from **replication bucket** when a source bucket replicates the uploaded object to the replication bucket.

I want to capture the event and use it for lambda or any other service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those wondering what the event will be, it will be Object Created.
I confirmed this by enabling event for bucket and captured all the events in eventbridge and it was object created.

I hope documentation will state this in future that for replication events too it will be Object Created